# Disable color matching in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, macos, colors, interface-builder

Is it possible to *completely* disable color matching in Interface Builder? In other words, I want to enter values for color properties as literal values without having IB mess with color space conversion;  just take the numbers exactly as I entered them and plop them in the nib.

(yes, I understand why it wants to do color space conversion -- I just don't want it to)